# Resolução de conflitos com o Meldmerge (Git, Github)

Tags: git, github

[image: SS]

A ferramenta não me permite subir as alterações do arquivo do meio, são essas as alterações novas que eu preciso comitar, mas ele não está indo, é justamente essa alteração que "ele quer" sobrescrever com uma das duas ao lado, que são desatualizadas.

Como proceder?

Isso ocorreu quando eu tentava fazer um *merge* da *branch* que criei para a master `$ git checkout MinhaBranch`

`$ git merge master`

Também tentei o inverso, da *master* para a `minhaBranch`, e continua o mesmo conflito.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Antes eu abria o arquivo com: `$ meld NomeDoArquvo` e por isso não tinha permissão para alterar os arquivos da *remote* e *local*, então configurei o *mergetool* e digite:

`$ git mergetool`

Pronto! a cada pergunta no terminal, eu dava enter e abria o meld no arquivo de conflito e conseguia prosseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi causado por abrir o **meld** incorretamente, assim ele não "possuia permissão" para alterar os arquivos da *local* e da *remote*.
Após configurá-lo, digitei:

`$ git mergetool`

E o meld inicia em cada conflito normalmente.

Para configurar o **mergetool**:

`git config --global mergetool.meld`

Comment: Caso resolvido marque como resolvido assim fica mais facil